# Ruby form auto submission Mechanize::ResponseCodeError

Tags: ruby, error-handling, mechanize

```
submit_form = agent.get("http://sample.com/NewTask.aspx").form("aspnetForm") do |f|
    f["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtNumber"] = "1234",
    f["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cmbText"] = "test",
    f["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$FUpload$fu"] = "",
    f["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn"] = "test"
    f.submit(f.button_with(:name => "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnOK"))
end
```

This is the code I wrote for the form auto submission using the mechanize lib for Ruby, it came back with `Mechanize::ResponseCodeError` as follow. I really don't see any error in my code, anyone could kindly let me know if this is a code error or something on the server side (say server prevents form auto submission)?

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.4/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:29
1:in `fetch': 500 => Net::HTTPInternalServerError for http://sample.com/NewTask.aspx -- unhandled response (Mechanize::ResponseCodeError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.4/lib/mechanize.rb:1207:in`post_form'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.4/lib/mechanize.rb:515:in `submit'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.4/lib/mechanize/form.rb:178:in`submit'
        from auto_post.rb:27:in `block in <main>'
        from (eval):23:in`form_with'
        from auto_post.rb:13:in `'

Comment: It says 500 Internal Server Error, you should check your server logs.

Comment: Thank KARASZI István for your reply, the thing is I dont have the access to the server...is there any other way to find out where exactly went wrong so that I could fix it?

Comment: You can check the actual response, maybe the error is inside (use `tcpdump` or the network part of the developer tools in your browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to proxy through a debugging proxy like fiddler or charles:

```
agent.set_proxy 'localhost', 8888
```

then proxy your browser similarly and compare the requests